# UPDATE if column is not null, if null then leave at null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET first_name = 'AAA',
    last_name = 'BBB',
    address1 = '123',
    address2 = 'Fake St.,',
    phone = '1234567',
    id = '11223344'
```

What should I use to only update each column if it is not null?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
update tableA
set first_name = case when first_name is null then null else 'aaa' end,
last_name = case when last_name is null then null else 'bbb' end,
...
```

Comment: Or `case when first_name is not null then 'aaa' end` as there is an implicit `else null` for unhandled cases.

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach less verbose (and less readable):

```
UPDATE TableA
SET first_name = left(  'AAA' + first_name, 3 )  ,
    last_name = left(  'BBB' + last_name, 3 )  ,
    address1 = left(  '123' + address1, 3 )  ,
    address2 = left(  'Fake St.,' + address2, len( 'Fake St.,' ) )  ,
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

For this example use the ISNULL function:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET first_name = ISNULL(first_name, NULL, 'AAA'),
    last_name = ISNULL(last_name, NULL, 'BBB'),
    (...)
GO
```